# How to make button invisible?

Tags: c#, button

Button02 created using toolbox.
Button03 created programatically
inside Method111, i able to use visible property of Button03, but when i'm in another method(let's say Method222()), i can't use the visible property. It's says out of context. I'm Using C#

```
private void Method111()
{
    Button Button03 = new Button();
    Button03.Size = Button02.Size;
    Button03.Location = new Point(Button02.Location.X + Button02.Width + A02,
                                  Button02.Location.Y);
    Button03.Visible = true;
    Button03.Text = "";
    Controls.Add(Button03);
    Button03.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
    };
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to tag your questions with the programming language you are asking about.

Comment: @Chris the `=>` makes me think that it's C#.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Yes, just noticed that as well. Still, only the author can tell us for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Button03` variable is local to your current function's scope. This means that you cannot access the variable outside of this function.

To remedy this you need to declare `Button03` in some scope that can be accessed from both functions, e.g. as a class member.

I can't know why you can access `Button02` because you have not posted the code that contains the declaration. However, my assumption is that your code looks something like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public Button Button02;

    private void Method111()
    {
        Button Button03;
        // Button03 is accessible because it is declared in this method
        // Button02 is accessible because it is declared in this class
    }

    private void SomeOtherMethd()
    {
        // Button03 is not accessible because it was declared in other method's scope
        // Button02 is accessible because it is declared in this class
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks chris but how will i declare this so that i can use outside function?

Comment: @DaveRyan This depends on your programming language and the structure of your application. Have a look at how `Button02` is declared as this seems to be accessible inside your function while not being declared there.

Comment: i"m using C#.. BUtton02 was declared automatically by the program.

Comment: @DaveRyan Everything is fixed in code somewhere. Have a look at your source code and find the declaration of `Button02`, using Visual Studio's Search feature if necessary.